# Integrating Firebase authentication with Django (DRF)

Tags: django, firebase, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework, firebase-authentication

I am developing a Django (DRF)/React web application and have integrated Firebase authentication using the email/password provider. The application requires additional user data, and I aim to link the Firebase user database with the Django user model. The primary objective is to implement a secure and efficient authentication system.

**Workflow:**

[image]

- Web client: Users sign up with their email and password, followed by the receipt of a verification email.
- Web client: Retrieve the ID token and send it, along with extra user data (e.g., first name, last name, organization, role), to the server.
- Server: Verify the ID token and authenticate the request using the **FirebaseAuthentication** class.
- Server: Check if the user exists in the Firebase database.
- Server: Create a user record in the Django user model if the user exists, ensuring data consistency between Firebase and Django.

I have implemented a Django authentication backend using the **FirebaseAuthentication** class, as shown below:

```
default_app = initialize_app()


class FirebaseAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):
        auth_header = request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION")
        if not auth_header:
            raise NoAuthToken("No auth token provided")

        id_token = auth_header.split(" ").pop()
        decoded_token = None
        try:
            decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
        except Exception:
            raise InvalidAuthToken("Invalid auth token")

        if not id_token or not decoded_token:
            return None
        try:
            uid = decoded_token.get("uid")
        except Exception:
            raise FirebaseError()
        user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=uid)
        return user, None
```

Is my implementation aligning with best practices for integrating Firebase authentication with Django? Are there any potential security risks or vulnerabilities in my implementation?